# NO SE PUDO ENCONTRAR LA FUNCIÓN FIT

Tags: r, modelos

Estoy realizando un modelo de clasificación. Dispongo de un dataframe con datos de pacientes (ficticios)y en función de los mismos, tengo que clasificarlos como propensos a tener una enfermedad coronaria o no.

He probado con el siguiente código, pero me aparece el mensaje: "no se pudo encontrar la función fit".

Parece que es porque no he cargado la libreria "parsnip" ni "ggplot2", pero es que no me permite cargar esta última.

¿alguna sugerencia para arreglarlo?

```
lr_hd_fit <- logistic_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glm") %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  fit(HeartDisease ~ ., data = training)
```

Comment: ggplot2 no tiene nada que ver aquí, ya que no estás graficando los resultados. Si las funciones que posees aquí son de la librería parsnip, debes cargarla previamente con `library(parsinp)` (ah, y claro `tidyverse`, `dpylr` o `magrittr` para ocupar los pipes. Si aún falla luego de cargar las librerías, puede ser un conflicto con una función del mismo nombre de otra librería. Para ello utiliza `parsinp::fit(HeartDisease ~ ., data = training)`

Comment: dplyr esta caragado El tema es que para cargar tidyverse, parece que necesita ggplot2. Te pongo el error:
 library("tidyverse")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

Comment: Debes cargar `parsnip` sí o sí. El mensaje te dice claramente que no encontró la función que intentas utilizar, y eso es porque el paquete necesario no está cargado